# Why I am getting junk character in the end of every C program I am writing

Tags: c

This is my program and I always get a `%` sign at the end of every program's output. For example in the end of output of the below program, I get:

```
name1 and name2: You will reach the top.%
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define message_for(a, b) \
        printf(#a " and " #b ": You will reach the top.'\0'")

int main() {
    message_for(name1, name2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the point of '\0'?

Comment: Remove `'\0'`, it is useless

Comment: [It's not reproducible](http://ideone.com/wVREgC). You *do* get a single quote at the end, but that's because you put it right there in the string you print.

Comment: Try with `printf(#a " and " #b ": You will reach the top.\n")`

Comment: By the way, how are you running a program like this? In a command line terminal? What is the prompt you have in that terminal?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however, you are right regarding NULL Character it was a waste try of avoiding % symbol in the end. Although with "\n" issue remains the same. I am running this program as a test program on cluster. As its the same scenario regarding the output with all programs on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\0` at the end of the string acts as a string terminator.  Your program should output this:

```
name1 and name2 : You will reach the top.'
```

without a trailing newline. Therefore, on Unix systems and on OS/X, the shell prompt will appear immediately after the `'`.  Your shell prompt is probably very simple and starts with a `%`. Here is a possible copy of your terminal screen:

```
% ./myprogram
name1 and name2 : You will reach the top.'% _
```

With `_` standing for the blinking cursor for the next command to be entered. You should always output a trailing newline at the end of your messages:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define message_for(a, b) \
    printf(#a " and " #b ": You will reach the top.\n")

int main(void) {
    message_for(name1, name2);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** you say you are running the program on an online service: there is a good chance adding a trailing newline to the output should fix the problem, otherwise it may be a feature of this platform to show exactly where the end of the program's output really is.

Comment: Thanks it really was only newline character as you said in the end of the output. :)

Comment: I think OP uses zsh: in some default configuration, zsh add a `%` at the end of line to notify that the previous output did not finish by a newline.